# Merge values of zip codes in collection and delete duplicate

Tags: javascript, typescript, collections, stream

I have a collection that has some cities and their zip codes, in some cases one city may have 2 zip codes ( madrid in this case is duplicated with 2 different zipcodes). The collection structure is as follows :

[image]

How can I group the values of zip codes  for duplicated cities that have different zip codes and keep only one entry for the duplicated one with values like this zipCode= zipcode1,zipcode2 In our case for Madrid zipcode value should be : zipCode=19,28 ?
using streams maybe or any method that could work

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the expected outcome would be? I'm a little unclear on the end goal.

Comment: the collection stay the same only for duplicated cities as Madrid  now have a the 2 zipcodes gathered in one value  zipCode=19,28  and now Madrid is not duplicated we only have unique city named madrid  thank you in advance

Comment: @SteveQuatrale I have adjusted the question

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be done a little more eloquently, but this will do the job!

```js
let data = [
  {zipCode: 28, name: "Madrid"},
  {zipCode: 38, name: "Tenerife"},
  {zipCode: 58, name: "Madrid"},
  {zipCode: 46, name: "Valencia"},
  {zipCode: 13, name: "Madrid"},
  {zipCode: 7, name: "Mallorca"},
  {zipCode: 21, name: "Valencia"},
];

function mergeZips(data){
  
  let newArray = [];
  let previousItem = {};
  
  // sort all the items alphabetically in the array
  data.sort((a,b) =>{
    let aa = a.name.toLowerCase(), bb = b.name.toLowerCase();
    
    if (aa < bb) {return -1;}
    else if (aa > bb) {return 1;}
    else {return 0;}
  });
  
  $(data).each((i) => {
    
    let item = data[i];
    item.zipCode = item.zipCode.toString();
    
    // if the name of the current item matches the name of the previous item, 
    // add the new zipcode to the old one
    if(item.name === previousItem.name){
      previousItem.zipCode = previousItem.zipCode + ', ' + item.zipCode;
    }
    // if it doesn't, it's unique --> push it to the array
    else {
      previousItem = item;
      newArray.push(previousItem);
    }
  });

  return newArray;
}

data = mergeZips(data);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Multimap

You can use a MultiMap (a Map where each key can have multiple values) to map each city to one or more zipcodes.

Here is an example using a [Rimbu MultiMap](https://rimbu.org/docs/collections/multimap)

```
import { SortedMultiMapSortedValue } from "@rimbu/core";

const data = [
  { id: 31, zipCode: 28, name: "Madrid" },
  { id: 32, zipCode: 38, name: "Tenerife" },
  { id: 33, zipCode: 58, name: "Madrid" },
  { id: 34, zipCode: 46, name: "Valencia" },
  { id: 35, zipCode: 13, name: "Madrid" },
  { id: 36, zipCode: 7, name: "Mallorca" },
  { id: 37, zipCode: 21, name: "Valencia" }
];

// Could use a Rimbu Stream here to avoid creating an extra array
const tuples = data.map((item) => [item.name, item.zipCode] as const);

// Create MultiMap from names to zipCodes
const namesToZipCodes = SortedMultiMapSortedValue.from(tuples);

console.log(namesToZipCodes.toString());
// logs:
// SortedMultiMapSortedValue(
//   Madrid -> [13, 28, 58],
//   Mallorca -> [7],
//   Tenerife -> [38],
//   Valencia -> [21, 46]
// )

// retrieve the zipCodes for Madrid as array
console.log(namesToZipCodes.getValues("Madrid").toArray());
// logs: [13, 28, 58]
```

Here is a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mountain-j8pjp?file=/src/index.ts)

#### Table

Depending on your needs you could also use a [Table](https://rimbu.org/docs/collections/table) to also store the object itself. It's basically a Map with 2 keys. This allows you, in addition to the data in the MultiMap, to store the source item itself for easy access.

See the [Rimbu docs](https://rimbu.org) for all the available collections, it could be that a different one even suits your needs better.